# Import Library Project with Android Studio 0.3.0

Tags: android, android-studio, library-project

I've just updated my Android Studio version to 0.3.0, and I still can't import a simple library project into my app project.
Even with the new Module Visual Interface. (You dont have to edit build.gradle - ???)

My Project Structure:

```
+JsonReaderproject
 +idea
 +gradle
 +JsonReader
  -build
  -src
  -everything else...
+External Libraries
```

These are my steps:

File>Project Structure (here I don't find any "Import Module"), I find that option when
select +JsonReaderProject main folder then View>Open Module Settings. Ok, then I click on >Import New Module, after doing the import, I select my +JsonReader folder in the same window, click on the right "Plus" button, Module Dependency, select my imported module and then Apply, OK.

With these steps I can reference the library in code, and use it, but it doesn't compile.

Answer (score 0):

In your build.gradle (under JsonReader), make sure to add your module dependencies :

```
dependencies {
        compile project(":YourImportedModule")
    }
```

This "dependencies" tag must be in your "android" tag. Like this :

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "18.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 18
    }

    dependencies {
        compile project(":YourImportedModule")
    }
```

Make sure that in your settings.gradle (at the root of the project), all your imported module must be in it, like that :

```
include ': JsonReader:', ':YourImportedModule', ':YourImportedModule1'
```

Comment: i've tried this method and it's not working my friend. here i post the resulting images and the error when compiling:
http://imageshack.us/a/img40/1500/8ga7.jpg
http://imageshack.us/a/img842/9356/6wes.jpg
http://imageshack.us/a/img542/4554/ciu1.jpg

Comment: In your screenshot, the "dependencies" tag is not IN the "android" tag like I said in my answer. Try that ;)

Comment: i corrected my mistake and added the dependency inside the Android tag, but still getting the same error. :(